# Invalid attempt to spread non iterable instance (In reducer of React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I have a unique situation and i needed some help.

```
userData : {
 isValidCheckup: true,
 accounts: {
  userAccount: [
    {
      accountType: 'checkings',
      includeInCheckup: false
    },
    {
      accountType: 'checkings',
      includeInCheckup: false
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the reducer.

```
case UPDATE_USER_DATA: {
  const newUserAccount = [...state.userData.userAccount] // ----ERRROR-----
  return {
   ...state,
   userData: {
     ...state.userData
   }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error at line `const newUserAccount = [...state.userData.userAccount]`
It says the following error on console

Invalid attempt to spread non iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non- array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method

Can someone please suggest a way around this. I want to loop through userAccount and update accountType property. Thats why i added `const newUserAccount = [...state.userData.userAccount]`

Comment: Try `{...state.userData.userAccount}`. Well, what are you changing in the reducer, tho?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging. Be sure to install the React developer tools that allow you to inspect props and state. Also install the Redux dev tools that allow you to inspect redux state and manipulate actions. Inspect the value of `state.userData.userAccount` to see why it causes an error.

Answer (score 3):

Your `userAccount` is nested under `accounts`, so try `[...state.userData.accounts.userAccount]` instead.